# What about the "static" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

It's a little used tag, and it's ambiguous: for some questions it refers to static electricity, and for some it refers to static variables in programming. I suggest to add a tag "static-electricity" and remove the "static" tag. I don't think for the programming questions the tag "static" is very useful.

Comment: I'm in favor of static-electricity. Perhaps the moderators can rename the tag? If there is ever some merit in tagging for static variables, and I am not convinced there is, that ought to be a separate, unambiguous tag.

Answer (score 2):

So looking at the general [static](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static) situation, I went ahead and cleared out the two other odd usages such as (static) [timing-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing-analysis). I also want to consider the [antistatic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antistatic) and [esd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esd) tags as well because these are really all similar topics. I agree that [static](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static) is not a good tag and could easily be renamed, but I would like to have a more comprehensive solution.

General topics covered and proposed retagging:

- Protecting a circuit from static discharge. This includes handling precautions and techniques for storage and manufacturing, as well as circuit design for ESD protection. Currently covered by primarily [antistatic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antistatic) and [esd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esd). This may be better suited to a new tag, [esd-protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esd-protection) or we could make the wiki for [esd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esd) more explicity inclusive.
- General static electricity phenomena. There are a few questions in [static](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static) that would be suitable for renaming to [static-electricity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-electricity).

I think the topics discussing ESD need a tag starting with "ESD" or else it won't pop up easily in the tag search results, but everything else seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can't we make "ESD" and "antistatic" synonyms of "static-electricity", so that they get renamed automagically, and that we don't end up with too many similar tags?

Comment: @radagast The reason I'm posting is to get consensus from the community before making an irreversible change. What you describe is certainly possible, but I don't think that your proposed mapping is ideal.

Comment: If there's less than, say, 10 questions that are purely about the physics of static electricity, I agree with @radagast that it makes sense to have `esd` and `static-electricity` as synonyms.